# Couldn't Connect to Mysql and Mysqli in My Localhost

Tags: server, apache2, mysql, php

I have problem with my newly installed via repo for apache2, mysql, php and phpmyadmin. I was following this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04) from digitalocean.

For now, my localhost is running and Ubuntu Apache2 default page is appeared. My phpmyadmin is also running and I have import several databases into it.

The issue is, everything in HTML are displayed. But everything that require mysql or mysqli are not functioning. I give two examples here:-

When try run using mysqli:-

```
$db = new mysqli_connect("localhost","adminmc","123adminmc456","moneychanger");

if($db->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}
```

The result is still like this:-

```
Unable to connect to database [Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)]
```

My first trial was using my root username and password. It was still prompt above error. I knew something is not right. I decided to use mysql instead.

When try run using mysql

```
$c = mysql_connect("localhost", "adminmc", "123adminmc456");
mysql_select_db("moneychanger");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT 'Hello, dear MySQL user!' AS _message FROM DUAL");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo htmlentities($row['_message']);
```

Ive got HTTP ERROR 500 instead which mentioned "This page isn’t working".

I honestly not sure what I am doing wrong. I follow the tutorial and even my mysql and phpmyadmin working fine. But I couldn't even connect to database using basic mysqli and mysql php script. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My apologies. Turn out that I was editing at the old lampp directory which is /opt/lampp/htdocs. I supposed to clear my notepadqq and open based on new directory which is /var/www/html. My bad and my mistake. Everything is fine now. Hopefully anyone encounter this kind of issue please do check your directory of files that you do editing.

thanks